# Function returning empty list

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, class

I have created an object class and am trying to use a for loop to create objects using data in a dataframe. I want these objects stored in a list, but the function is returning an empty list.

Class:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, date, description, amount, category):
        self.date = date
        self.description = description 
        self.amount = amount 
        self.category = category
```

function:

```
def objectify(df):
    for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
        transactions = []
        dt = str(df.iloc[(i, 0)])
        descr = str(df.iloc[(i, 1)])
        amnt = float(df.iloc[(i, 2)])
        cat = str(df.iloc[(i, 10)])
        transactions.append(Transaction(dt, descr, amnt, cat))
        return transactions
```

when `objectify(df)` then `print(transactions)` is called, [] is returned, where I would be expecting a list of transactions

Comment: put `transactions = []` and `return` statement out of the loop

Comment: Did you assign the retuned value from `objectify` to `transactions`? And move the `return` statement out of the loop, you return after the first iteration.

Comment: can you provide the code lines with call of the function and the line with the print?

Comment: @Guy moved the return statement, does `transactions.append` not assign the value from `objectify` to `transactions`

Comment: @JacobCanby No, it assign it to the local `transactions` inside the loop that you override every iteration.

Comment: The code, as shown in the question, would return either a list with exactly one Transaction element or None if len(df.index) < 2. It cannot return an empty list

Answer (score 2):

@RomanPerekhrest's [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77081082/function-returning-empty-list#comment135885429_77081082) should be the solution for your problem.

Here is another variant (*shorter and more efficient*) to create the list of `Transaction` objects.

```
def objectify(df):

    dmap = {
        "Date": "string", "Description": "string",
        "Amount": "float", "Category": "string"
    } # you might need to adjust the columns names and/or their types
    
    return [
        Transaction(*vals) for vals in df.astype(dmap)[dmap.keys()].to_numpy()
    ]

transactions = objectify(df)
```

Output :

```
print(transactions)

[<__main__.Transaction at 0x7d750f5a2140>,
 <__main__.Transaction at 0x7d750f5a0820>,
 ...]
```